# Keyboard shortcuts don't work properly after upgrade ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04

I upgraded my ubuntu from 18.04 LTS to ubuntu 19.10 and then I upgrade to ubuntu 20.4 LTS.

Many programs had problems and after `purge` and `install` again problems solved.

But now my keboard shortcuts like `windows key` and `delete key` not working.

How can i solve this ?